# Caching a .net page with or without metatags

Tags: html, asp.net, caching

I got a question and it is keeping me quite busy and I can not discover why.

I have a asp.net page which runs through IIS10 and I want to make sure that for every request, whether it is a POST request or a GET request, the content is not stored as cache.

When searching on the internet a lot of people saying that you could force the browser not to cache by using metatags. Now I added the following metatags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
```

Which I suspect should force the browser not to cache the page. Doing research, with different browsers (ie, chrome and firefox), showed me per request the response headers and the request headers.

Now the weird part is that in the past like six years ago I needed those metatags to explicit not cache the page. But now in current browsers when I removed those metatags the same **cache-control value**  (for all the browsers) regarding the response headers and request headers are showed. Which I am wondering why does those metatags does not have any influence anymore while back in the days it did?